# Ошибка "variable might not have been initialized"

Tags: java, компиляция

Возник вопрос по логике кода. Почему компилятор не пропускает такой код?

```
String testStr;
if (check > 0) {
  testStr = "abc";
}
System.out.println(testStr != null ? testStr: "0");
```

При компиляции выдаётся ошибка:

> Error:(134, 32) java: ... variable testStr might not have been initialized

Хотя вроде как логичным будет просто вывести "0" в случае, если `testStr` не было инициализировано... Какая тут логика?

Comment: если переменная не инициализирвоана, то ты не сможешь проверить условие `testStr != null`, а условие в if может не выполнится. поэтому компилятор ругается

Comment: нужно явно инициализировать testStr с помощью null: `String testStr = null`. Иначе получается неопределенность, если подходить к коду строго, то компилятор должен выделить место под переменную, но по этому адресу может оказаться любой мусор, не равный null.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Есть два варианта интерпретации данного кода:

1. Программист хотел объявить переменную с каким-то значением, но допустил ошибку в коде: пропустил присвоение значения либо блок `else`. В этом случае компилятор поможет ему найти ошибку.
2. Программист полагает, что `testStr` будет инициализировано как `null` по умолчанию. В этом случае компилятор заставит программиста инициализировать переменную как `null` явно.

Разработчики Java пришли к выводу, что:

- важно отловить возможные ошибки;
- неудобства, связанные с инициализацией локальных переменных, незначительны.

Обязательная инициализация локальных переменных определена в [спецификации Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html):

> **Chapter 16. Definite Assignment**
>
> Each local variable ([§14.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4)) and every blank final field ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4), [§8.3.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2)) must have a definitely assigned value when any access of its value occurs.
>
> An access to its value consists of the simple name of the variable (or, for a field, the simple name of the field qualified by this) occurring anywhere in an expression except as the left-hand operand of the simple assignment operator = (§15.26.1).
>
> **For every access of a local variable or blank final field x, x must be definitely assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs.**
>
> *Перевод (из книги «[Язык программирования Java SE 8. Подробное описание](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1875-8.html)»)*
>
> **Глава 16. Определенное присваивание**
>
> Каждая локальная переменная (§14.4) и каждое пустое final-поле (§4.12.4, §8.3.1.2) должны иметь определенно присвоенное значение при любом обращении к их значениям.
>
> Обращение к их значениям состоит из простого имени переменной (или, в случае поля, простого имени поля, квалифицированного ключевым словом `this`), находящегося в любом месте выражения, за исключением левого операнда оператора присваивания = (§15.26.1).
>
> **Для каждого обращения к локальной переменной или к пустому final-полю x, x должно быть определенно присвоено до этого обращения, иначе генерируется ошибка времени компиляции.**

Посмотрите также обсуждения этого вопроса в английской версии:

- [Why are local variables not initialized in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java)
- [Why must local variables, including primitives, always be initialized in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560685/why-must-local-variables-including-primitives-always-be-initialized-in-java)

Answer (score 10):

В Java локальные переменные не имеют значения по умолчанию. Это означает что при простом объявлении переменной у неё не будет значения. В приведённом коде при check<=0 переменная так и останется не инициализированной при обращении к ней, на что и ругается компилятор.

```
String testStr=null;
```

Это решит проблему